# Can't access NSPasteboard using PyObjC

Tags: python, objective-c, pyobjc

I'm trying to read OSX Clipboard using PyObjC.

Inside python shell

```
import AppKit
>>> clip = AppKit.NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
>>> dir(clip)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

Many pasteboard attributes are missing. So `clip.stringForType_(AppKit.NSStringPboardType)` results in AttributeError.

Comment: Do other objects have the proper attributes? What are your PyObjC and OS X versions?

Comment: Yes, `dir(AppKit.NSPasteboard)` shows alot of attributes. OSX version - 10.9.4. How can I check PyObjC version?

Answer (score 2):

Here's some python which will read in plain text from the clipboard. If you want to include other types, then you add them to the array `myFavouriteTypes` (and use `dataForType`).

```
from AppKit import NSPasteboard, NSStringPboardType 

myFavoriteTypes = [NSStringPboardType]
pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
best_type = pb.availableTypeFromArray_(myFavoriteTypes)
if best_type:
    clipString = pb.stringForType_(best_type)
    if clipString:
        print (clipString)  
else:
    print ("No clipboard image data was retrieved.")
    print ("These types were available:")
    print (pb.types())
```