# copy an PIL image to the macOS clipboard with Python

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I am trying to copy a image created in PIL to the macOS clipboard.

I found 2 ways:

1. Using Pasteboard (pypi.org/project/pasteboard) but that one does not seem to work with Python 3.10 (I get a wheels error when trying to install it).
2. The other way is from here ([Copy an image to MacOS clipboard using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008175/copy-an-image-to-macos-clipboard-using-python)) and uses the following code:

   ```
   import subprocess

   subprocess.run(["osascript", "-e", 'set the clipboard to (read (POSIX file 
   'image.jpg') as JPEG picture)'])
   ```

I tried playing around with this second approach but I cannot get it to work with an image created in Pillow. For example:

```
import subprocess
from PIL import Image 

image = Image.open('img.png') 
subprocess.run(["osascript", "-e", 'set the clipboard to (read (POSIX file '???') as JPEG picture)'])
```

In the original post the '???' was an image.jpg, so how could I insert the PIL data in there? I tried some variations but kept on getting the same error:

```
CFURLGetFSRef was passed an URL which has no scheme (the URL will not work with other CFURL routines)
22:67: 2023-01-12 13:53:42.227 osascript[1361:27923] CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed an URL which has no scheme
execution error: Can’t make file ":image" into type file. (-1700)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will copy the image as a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs):

```
import base64
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image 
image = Image.open('img.png') 
buffered = BytesIO()
image.save(buffered, format="PNG")
base64_enc = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue())
print("data:image/png;base64,"+"".join(map(chr,base64_enc)))
```

which you then will be able to paste in your browser, and probably not in file manager though

if this didn't answer your question then you probably have to find a library that supports mac clipboard.

Comment: Is that going to work for images as well? From the PyPi page it seems to only support text

Comment: You can also try the AppKit library as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692010/cant-access-nspasteboard-using-pyobjc).